# how to put an @HTML helper inside a validation in ASP.NET Core 2.0 MVC

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

What I want to do is a validation in which two action links will be rendered or not if the user is a member of the Role "User".

So far this is the part of the view that I am talking about without the validation:

```html
<td>
 <a asp-controller="Manage" asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.OwnerID">Edit</a> |
 <a asp-controller="Manage" asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.OwnerID">Delete</a> |
 @Html.ActionLink("Approve", "Approve", new { id = @item.OwnerID }, new { onclick = "return confirm('Are you sure you wish to approve this user?');" }) |
 @Html.ActionLink("Reject", "Reject", new { id = @item.OwnerID }, new { onclick = "return confirm('Are you sure you wish to reject this user?');" }) |
 <a asp-controller="Manage" asp-action="UpdateRole" asp-route-id="@item.OwnerID">Change Role</a>
</td>
```

Here is what I need help with.

I want to do something like this **(the `If(@item.RoleName =="User")`** in following code:

```html
<td>
  <a asp-controller="Manage" asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.OwnerID">Edit</a> |
  <a asp-controller="Manage" asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.OwnerID">Delete</a> |
**@if(item.RoleName == "User")**
{
   @Html.ActionLink("Approve", "Approve", new { id = @item.OwnerID }, new { onclick = "return confirm('Are you sure you wish to approve this user?');" }) |
   @Html.ActionLink("Reject", "Reject", new { id = @item.OwnerID }, new { onclick = "return confirm('Are you sure you wish to reject this user?');" }) |
**}**
<a asp-controller="Manage" asp-action="UpdateRole" asp-route-id="@item.OwnerID">Change Role</a>
</td>
```

The compiler is expecting a `;` after the second `@Html.ActionLink` and when I go to the view I get invalid term after `}`

May I have your help on how to get that working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It picks up your `|`s as the bitwise `OR` operators (which you can tell by the fact it highlights them as code). Manually switch back to HTML mode at the pipe characters:

```
@if (item.RoleName == "User")
{
    @Html.ActionLink("Approve", "Approve", ... ) @:|
    @Html.ActionLink("Reject", "Reject", ... ) @:|
}
```